# Badge request - 'Ignored'

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Having 10, 50, 300 answers with:

- 5 or more upvotes
- The highest voted answer on a question
- Question has no accepted answer after 30 days
- Question is not a community wiki

It's really annoying when you provide a decent answer to a question and the asker neglects to accept it, this would go some way to compensating for that.

Comment: For the third criterion, do you mean without an accepted answer? Generally, "unanswered" on Stack Exchange means no upvoted or accepted answers.

Comment: I do, I'll clarify that

Comment: Badges are generally supposed to encourage good behaviour. I'm not sure about this one though. Isn't this a camouflaged rant? :)

Comment: Not really, as John pointed out this will encourage more questions to be answered by people who currently don't answer questions from new users or users with a low accept rate (and the 5+ constraint requires that they are good!).

Comment: RIght, but I'd rather do it from the other way on: encourage the questioner to accept answers. Although this might not always have the desired effect on certain types of questioners.

Comment: I would like to have the bronze medal awarded at 5, so I can get it. :-)

Comment: @BalusC Better to encourage *good* answers to these questions, rather than the asker to blindly accept *bad* answers. Having good answers should in theory make them more likely to accept!

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with certain types of questioners :)

Comment: I'd call it the "Loser" badge.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like many badge requests, but this one seems good.  I've seen many people who will only answer if the asker has a high accept rate.  I think this badge would be a good incentive for people to answer *all* questions.

Answer (score 2):

Also:

- question isn't Community Wiki

Comment: Yes, agreed, I'll add it to the spec

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, absolutely sure you want yet another badge?  I propose to merge an existing badge instead.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1069/badge-request-ignored-unsung-hero-2

This shows the usual suspects getting 3 more badges. *<sub>But that does not mean it is a bad thing</sub>*

```
441 Bronze
47  Silver
9   Gold
```

Just as a thought, maybe we can tweak unsung hero to include this, since the goals seem similarly aligned.

---

[unsung-hero](/questions/tagged/unsung-hero) - Awarded for percentage of accepted answers having 0-vote answers.
It [this answer][1] and many more like it worthy of a "hero" tag?

From comments below, I would like to see [unsung-hero](/questions/tagged/unsung-hero) swung around to include dual pathing - either via the original criteria (0-vote answers) or via the criteria proposed here.

Comment: Maybe tweak the values at which you get the badge, but it encourages more good answers (where currently there is a drought) so why not?

Comment: Nice query. The majority of the users in this list already gives *damn good* answers in general (and have a plenty of badges for it already). I can't imagine that *they* ever care about this badge. Maybe you should add an extra parameter which represents the % of total answers like as done with Tenacious and Unsung Hero? Still, I'm not sure of the feasibility of such a badge :)

Comment: Possibly, it is the evil twin of unsung hero I guess

Comment: @fred for "good" answers, there are already nice/good/great answers as well as enlightened. For consistent behaviour, there is already the legendary series.

Comment: @BalusC I was never a fan of Unsung Hero, only because it discriminates against those who already have loads of badges (and rep). But if we merge that with this, it would be cool again.

Comment: Me neither. ---

Comment: I also like the idea of combining this with unsung hero.

Comment: How exactly do you think they should be combined, either the current set of constraints or these ones?

Comment: @fredley exactly. Either path is valid - 0-vote accepted **or** 5-vote+ unaccepted (in summary)

Comment: Why did you include the `[unsung-hero]` tag? Tags are not badges, and those tags don't even link to any questions.

Comment: @pop It's just styling, is it so *wrong*?

Comment: @Richard Well... kinda, yeah.

Comment: @pop and that's because...? the "code sample" is not code either, but I prefer it to `>`. Should I be losing rep for these breaches?

Comment: @Richard, I didn't downvote you; nobody has. It just seems semantically wrong.

Comment: @pop `I didn't downvote you` I never claimed that. It was a [tongue-in-cheek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek) comment which reads *"is that a punishable offence"* - currency on SE being "rep"? Otherwise, I like my style with all due respect :)

Comment: @Richard, ah, I didn't know it was a joke. Alright, that's fine, it's your post. I was just curious if there was some reason beyond style.